# Javascript performance improvement in browsers over years

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, visualization

i'm a teacher in cartography and i'm preparing a course about client-side webmapping with JS apis and libs.

I searched the web for sources about browsers improvement in javascript performance, but i can't find recent data.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: This kind of question doesn't belong here. Sorry.

Comment: [here's something to look at](http://arewefastyet.com/)

Comment: Nice but here the data are to recent, only one year :/

Comment: @LaurentJégou: just compare IE6 to Chrome, IE6's over a decade old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for up to date data, you can give jsPerf a go.

http://jsperf.com/

They use a service called BrowserScope, http://code.google.com/p/browserscope/. From their home page, http://www.browserscope.org/:

> Browserscope is a community-driven project for profiling web browsers.

They have a history of JavaScript performance in various browsers and is updated frequently.

---

If you're interested in getting performance throughout the ages of JavaScript you can also run it yourself in Virtual Machines across various browsers.

Comment: Also http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=91086 and http://www.jstat.org/ might help too.

Comment: Browserscope is very nice, with a graph of browser perfs since 2001, thanks !